# // * Use a `for-loop` to increment `726` with the value `4`, `17` times

Tags: javascript

// * Use a `for-loop` to increment `726` with the value `4`, `17` times.

My Code

```
var sum = 726;
var i = 0;
for(var i; i <= 17; i+=4) {
    
     document.write(sum + i + "</br>");
 }
```

It increments only 5 times with my code, I need it to increment 17 times.
Im stuck, can someone help me out?

Comment: because you are adding 4 to i. You are not looping 17 times because 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20 <-- greater than 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can do this.

You can increment your `sum += 4` in every loop.

I have removed `i <= 17` to `i < 17`

So that loop will run for 17 times

```
var sum = 726;
for(let i = 0; i < 17; ++i) {
    console.log(sum+=4)
 }
```